# How can I use Auth to create the function "Remember Me"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some doubts here on how to do the "Remember Me" method, I have poor knowledge on how to use Auth that I have seen a lot on the internet.

So my question is how can I use the Auth to store my credential of login and when I toggled my switch so that it "remembers" the credentials?

**EDIT1:**

After my post i achive what i want, already can stay logged in. My problem now is i store the username and pass, but because when i login normally it goes throw a webservice that wil, after login, give me some info from the server that is needed to continue using the app. How can i steel go on on with exactly with the same session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how users enter the app ? You can use local storage to save if a user has logged in already `FIRSTTIMELOGIN = true`, and check that on your Splashscreen

You can also use [AccountStore](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/) to store important details which uses your key chain.

```
AccountStore.Create (this).Save (eventArgs.Account, "UserDetails");
```

Comment: After my post i achive what i want, already can stay logged in. My problem now is i store the username and pass, but because when i login normally it goes throw a webservice that wil, after login, give me some info from the server that is needed to continue using the app. How can i steel go on on with exactly with the same session?